# How to make my div load hidden before visibility is toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code here that I'm planning to make a menu with that allows the user to toggle the visibility of it. However, I'm not not sure how I can load the page with the div hidden. I'm trying to make it so that it starts hidden, and can be shown by clicking a button, but instead, it starts visible.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav").click(function(){
    $("#items").toggle();
  });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav"><a href="#"><p>Toggle</p></a></div>
<div id="items"><p>Content</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make the content to display none using css and then You can use jquery fadeToggle or slideToggle functions

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav").click(function(){
    $("#items").fadeToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="nav"><a href="#"><p>Toggle</p></a></div>
<div id="items" style="display:none"><p >Content</p></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice! The fading is not even something I considered, so I might use this!

Comment: yeah sure and If you think this answer is correct please accept this answer.

Comment: Works nicely with little Javascript. I think I'm gonna go with this :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
#nav {
   visibility: hidden; /* if you want the element to occupy space but not be seen */
   display: none; /* if you want the element to not take up space */
}
```

You can also do this in-line HTML `<div style="display:none;"></div>`

To unhide:

```
$("#nav").show(); // for display: none;
$("#nav").css('visibility', 'visible'); // for visibility : hidden;
```

And, a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgsz0zj8/4/)

Comment: Works good! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. I guess it's probably because I wasn't quite sure how this function worked. I wasn't sure if it modified the CSS or... now that I think of it, that was the only possibility. Boy, I'm stupid. ;)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it! Please accept the answer if if solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is non-JavaScript compatible too, I use a `jshidden` style on the elements and style them out based on a class added to the body:

```
<div id="nav" class="jshidden"><a href="#"><p>Toggle</p></a></div>
```

The secret is a snippet of JavaScript in the header of the page to set a `js` class on `body` if JavaScript is enabled:

e.g.

```
<script>document.body.className+=' js';</script>
```

and then styling to hide any `jshidden` items

css:

```
body.js jshidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Your toggle code will override the styling, with inline styles, so will work as-is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav").click(function(){
    $("#items").toggle();
  });
});
```

The advantage to all this is that the site will display the content if JS is not enabled (not a huge priority nowadays, but you never know when you might need this) :)